# How can I generate a SWC from asset files dynamically?

Tags: actionscript, swc, compc

Lets say you have 3 swf files in a directory:

/game/assets/

1.swf
2.swf
3.swf

What I need to do, is package these up into a SWC File, and then move that SWC file to the libs/ directory.

I plan to use ant, so this step must always occur before the compliation stage.

Today I use a VBS file to generate a XML file. Then I use that XML file to generate a AssetMap which is a series of [Embeds]  (1.swf, 2.swf, 3.swf) which are ByteArrays.

I then pass these byte arrays to a loader.loabytes to generate a MovieClip.

But this "real time bytearray conversion" as far too slow. Id prefer I could have direct access to instances like I do with a SWC.

Can anyone offer me advice?